# What reason of using ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST

Tags: php, flags, arrayobject

I don't find any example of using ArrayObject with ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST flag.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.setflags.php
Can you give me any example of using ArrayObject with this flag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's an example on [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php#arrayobject.constants.std-prop-list) in the ArrayObject documentation.

Comment: Can you please provide an example that demonstrates how using that constant makes a difference in contrast to not using that constant? Because the documentation does not give any example.

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r Did you look at the page I linked to? There's a demonstration by MarkAndrewSlade that shows the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I've used his example and *it seems that this does not work any longer* with current PHP versions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15960458/2261774

Answer (score 7):

Since PHP 5.3, this flag does not have any influence any longer.

http://3v4l.org/Fk3Qu

Output for 5.3.0 - 5.5.0beta2

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [prop] => prop data
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [arr] => array data
        )

)
ArrayObject Object
(
    [prop] => prop data
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [arr] => array data
        )

)
```

Output for 5.1.0 - 5.2.17

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [prop] => prop data
)
ArrayObject Object
(
    [arr] => array data
)
```

This has been also reported as a bug:

- [Bug #45595 - ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST does not behave as documented with foreach](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45595)